# Identifying Probability Distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution

Much is being made today about the effect of exercise on BMI in young people today. A study was conducted to assess the factors affecting exercise. Study participants were asked ‘How many minutes per week do you participate in moderate or vigorous exercises.’  One of the study questions focused on what factors might contribute to the amount of exercise a young person does (sex, age, asthma status, etc).

What would be the probability distribution for this, along with the parameters? This one is giving me a hard time. I believe the measurement for the outcome variable is qualitative ordinal.
thanks!!!

Comment: You haven't provided much information to go on. In fact, it isn't even clear what "this" refers to: would it be the *frequency* distribution of the reported time per week or--arguably much more relevant to the actual problem--would it be a *probability* distribution to model the responses *conditional* on the other factors?  If it's the former then in what sense do you view an amount of time per week as being merely "qualitative" and "ordinal"?

Comment: This is unclear.  My blog post [how to ask a statistics question](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/) may help you write a better question.